# Is it possible to force GCC to pad string constants in .rodata

Tags: c, gcc, memory-alignment

I'm working on porting some code to an environment with more strict alignment requirements than x86 has, but I'm changing/testing on an x86 Linux machine for the time being due to this being easier for hardware access reasons, among other things.

I've distilled the first problem that I've run into into the following   concise example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define DMQUOTE_LOG "DMQUOTELOG"

void aFunction (const char *configPath)
{
    char LogFilename[BUFFER_SIZE] __attribute ((aligned));

//     printf ("A\n");
    strcpy (LogFilename, configPath);
    strcat (LogFilename, DMQUOTE_LOG);

    printf ("Log: %s\n", LogFilename);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    __asm__("pushf\n"  
            "orl $0x40000, (%esp)\n"  
            "popf");  

    aFunction ("");

    return 0;
}
```

Running this code as is provides the expected output. However, uncommenting the other printf causes a bus error to trigger on the strcat line.

It looks to me as if the reason for this is that by introducing a second string constant, the constant from the define is shifted so that it's not aligned. This is upheld by noticing that if the string constant is changed from "A\n" to "AAA\n", everything works again (and magically gcc replaces the call to printf with a call to puts and drops the \n from the constant).

Is there some nice way to make gcc insert extra padding between all of the string constants that it's inserting into the .rodata section so that things align properly?

[EDIT]

As mentioned by fucanchik below, here's what the .rodata section of the above is (with the extra printf enabled):

```
    .file   "sample.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "A"
.LC1:
    .string "DMQUOTELOG"
.LC2:
    .string "Log: %s\n"
    .text
.globl aFunction
...
```

There is no alignment forced, which makes sense because I'm compiling under x86, which doesn't strictly require it. Naturally, modifying the assembler to this has the desired effect. However, I can't see a way to get gcc to apply this on its own on the fly. This may of course be moot if glibc itself can't handle being run in this mode in the general case, though.

```
    .file   "sample.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "A"
    .align 4,0
.LC1:
    .string "DMQUOTELOG"
.LC2:
    .string "Log: %s\n"
    .text
.globl aFunction
...
```

Comment: which command line do you use to compile?

Comment: Properly aligning string literals or at least making sure that standard string functions deal with unaligned strings seems like something that should be handled with a GCC/libc port. For manually aligning individual strings, I found the following: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-10/msg00068.html.

Comment: @fukanchik just a simple "gcc sample.c".

Comment: @Ulfalizer I'm afraid you may be right but I was hoping that something like this was possible. The fact that you have to jump through hoops to turn alignment checking on makes me worry that glibc doesn't take too many pains by default, though.

Comment: gcc should automatically apply platform required alignment. try compiling with gcc -S sample.c. This will produce assembly output which might give some clues.

Comment: @fukanchik it doesn't show anything special happening, which makes sense I guess since x86 doesn't have any specific alignment requirements. Looks like the better way to go might be to just to make my own small subset of the libc that's more compliant.

Comment: Are you running a compiler/using a libc that is actually ported to this odd architecture that doesn't seem to follow normal x86 alignment requirements ?

Comment: @nos I assume so since this is just a vanilla Slackware Linux machine, and that's what falls out of gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be any way to accomplish this, at least with GCC. Testing seems to indicate that although the compiler will align integers, doubles and so on,because string constants are made of characters and alignment for character data is on byte boundaries, the compiler feels no need to align them.

The particulars of this bus error seem to indicate that glibc uses optimized routines that copy data words at a time without checking for alignment first (having not looked at the source, I don't know if this is true or not however).

This led me to investigating [musl](http://www.musl-libc.org/), an alternative libc implementation that is simple to install and use on a project by project basis.The C source code of the musl version of strcat takes care to copy unaligned bytes before copying words at a time, and thus this particular issue goes away, although naturally others remain.